# this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()is not working in RCP product

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, product, rcp

`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(IMAGE_URL)` is working perfectly when  I am trying to run my RCP application from Eclipse. But, when I am running it as a product, it is not running.

`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` returns `null´. Any clue how to solve this?

Note: I have tried to solve this using `Activator.getDefault().getBundle()`. But this as well is not working. It seems that `Activator.getDefault() = null` which means that plugin is not actiavted. I also tried to put a break point there. Indeed the plugin variable in `null` in Activator.

What should I do?

Comment: `getResourceAsStream()` is meant to load resource from the **class path** and if it returns `null` it means that the resource you are looking for is not on your class path. Where does `IMAGE_URL` point to?

Comment: A problem that happens all to often to me is to create a jar with compiled class files only and no resource files.  When you search for non-class files, you won't find them because they aren't there!  I would double check that everything is where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FileLocator`:

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

InputStream is = FileLocator.openStream(bundle, new Path("relative path"), false);
```

Other methods of `FileLocator` will give you a URL instead of a stream.

Comment: one more issue is there.now, it not giving any null pointer ..but... the image are not showing for some unknown reason. Can you shed some light?

Comment: That seems like a different question and you would have to show us your code.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I will create a new question for that purpose.

Comment: here is the new link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038375/icons-or-images-are-not-appearing-in-rcp-application-after-exporting-as-a-produc

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The reason was the lack of resources in the product build. Check `MANIFEST.MF > Build` like on picture below and make sure that resources is selected to include in the binary build.

[image]

For example, if you use the resource from icons folder it's will work perfectly when you run application from eclipse. After export product, this resource is not available.